# CHOWN: What does "id -u" represent

Tags: filesystem, security

I am working to get Mongodb running on a Ubuntu server install.  In reviewing the [instructions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix) I needed to create a "\data\db" directory in the root drive.  At which point I needed to alter the owner using the CHOWN command as follows:

```
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

When I issue that command as it appears in the quick start guide I receive

```
chown: invalid user: 'id -u'
```

I am new to Linux, so what I don't understand is what the 'id -u' was supposed to mean.  When I replace with my user name the command completes just fine and mongo runs.  Can someone help me understand what the short hand 'id -u' would communicate to an expert Linux user that it did not to me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `id -u` prints out your "numeric user ID" (short: UID); as you already noticed, it is the same as spelling out your username in full on the `chown` command line.  Indeed, the following command invocations should all have the same effect:

```
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
sudo chown $USER /data/db
```

The reason why it did not work as expected has likely to do with the quotes: they have to be *backquotes* (ASCII char 0x60), whereas the `chown` error message suggests that you used single quotes (ASCII char 0x27).

You can find a very thorough explanation of UNIX shell quoting [here](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html#sect:shell-quot).

Comment: +1 for backticks. OP: There's a difference, in most shells, between "normal" single quotes (') and "backtick" quotes (`). Make sure you use the right ones.

Comment: Thank you, I did not even notice the subtle difference in quotes, nor did I know it would cause an issue.  I really appreciate the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

It returns your user id. Run `man id` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`id -u` prints your user id on the system. As an alternative you can just run this command:

`sudo chown <user> /data/db` replacing `<user>` with your username on the system.